# Why does my Fujifilm FinePix S1800 have far greater shutter lag in EVF mode than in LCD mode?

Tags: fujifilm, performance, lcd, evf

The shutter lag on my Fujifilm FinePix S1800 is much longer in EVF mode (just under half a second) than in LCD mode (about 0.15 seconds).  What would explain this anomaly?

Comment: I would guess a firmware bug since, as far as I know, the LCD and EVF are getting their data in the same way. The only real difference is a minor one in the resolution which, I suppose, could cause one to have more processing over the other and so make the camera a little less responsive. However, since this is all guess, I just posted a comment.

Comment: Are you sure you've controlled for all variables? That sounds like the sort of difference you'd expect between all of the auto focus / exposure running and not.

Answer (score 1):

As has been addressed in a comment to your question, it could do with the amount of memory the camera has, and how much processing it needs to do. If all other parameters are equal (settings, subject, exposure), then I have no idea. The EVF has **less** pixels than the LCD, so it should process quicker, which isn't your case.

The only other thing I can suggest, is asking whether you're encounter actual shutter lag, or just EVF refresh rate lag?